# Net-Dyn ac1200-usb-wi-fi-adapter dkms error upon install

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, dkms

I have an AC1200 USB Wi-Fi Adapter from Net-dyn. I had this working in 18.04 following the guide from cilynx/rtl88x2bu on github.

I upgraded to 20.04 and it was working.... Then I thought I should go into software & updates > additional drivers and change my video drivers from X.org X server to Nvidia 440 (proprietary,tested) I got an Gefore 1030 in my pc..

Then I rebooted, and my wi-dongle was gone... and it's still gone... I can find it with lsusb...

When I try following the guide again from cilynx, I got this error 
" asle@asle-Ubuntu:~/rtl88x2bu$ sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.4.0-26-lowlatency cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-5.4.0-26-lowlatency package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located "

I did try 
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo reboot now 
And got the same error

I can't figure it out, so I am asking for some help..

REgards
Asle

Comment: How did lowlatency kernel appear? What is the distro? Either install headers, or remove this kernel.

Comment: I got Ubuntu 20.04 ( normal )

Comment: If it is a vanilla Ubuntu, so how a lowlatency kernel is involved? Did you install it?

Comment: I have not installed it..

Comment: Well. then somebody else has installed it :-) So as I wrote, install the headers or use a generic kernel.

Comment: hehe...I don't know... can you tell me how I install generic kernel ?

Comment: `sudo apt install linux-generic`. Then remove lowlatency packages using e.g. synaptic.